# How to make Ghost Pepper Queso

Tags: dip

I have an event coming up and the person who usually brings the popular 'Ghost Pepper Cheese Dip' can't make it.

I've order some 'Smoked and Dried Bhut Jolokia Ghost Chili Pepper Pods' but I have not idea how to deal with them.

I figure I need to soak them, then mince them and integrate them into a queso.

But that seems to too simple...insanely hot peppers, meat and cheese.

I'm thinking Velvetta, 80/20 hamburger, rotel, cumin...and maybe sour cream (to kill some of the fire)...

I'm make shots in the dark.

Any advice would be welcomed.

Comment: Can you describe their version in any detail so folks could try to help you replicate it? Without that, people are stuck kind of guessing, and you'd probably be better off just googling for recipes (or asking them for their recipe).

Comment: I'm not really interested in duplicating his offering,  but just trying to make a good dish.  Stupid hot dish but yummy

Comment: Honestly it looked like a normal dip... You took a bite,  said yum,  and then the heat hit you.

Comment: Hello lunknown, I am afraid that, if you don't specify what problem you are trying to solve, your question will be closed as a recipe request, or as too broad. I can't find any question in your description, you are simply listing what you are planning to do. What information are you after?

Comment: Or perhaps your friend bought a jar of [Mrs. Renfro's Ghost Pepper Scary Hot Nacho Cheese Sauce](https://www.amazon.com/Mrs-Renfros-Nacho-Cheese-Pepper/dp/B00E872PB8) which contains a Velveeta-like cheese product, tomato, onion, and lots of peppers (green chile, sweet red, sweet green, jalapeno, ghost).

Comment: I changed the question title to be more of a question.

Comment: You still haven't explained how it is different from a recipe request. Have you read our scope? http://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic. Recipe requests are off topic. "Does ingredient X pair well with ingredient Y" is also off topic. So what exactly do you want to know, and how is it different from these two?

Comment: @Iunknown : the problem is that it's like asking for a meatloaf recipe -- in any community cookbook, there are generally 3-5 of them ... so the number of possible variations in too large to give a useful answer.    In your case, the easiest thing to do is ask the person who usually brings it.  If you try making it, and it doesn't come like what you wanted, then tell us what you did (ingredients & procedures), and how it differed from what you wanted to make.

Comment: I like queso, but have never made one.  Now I have a chance.  I figured I'd start with a something like this http://www.browneyedbaker.com/crock-pot-queso-dip-recipe/....but I'm sure that replacing jalapeños with ghost peppers would be dumb.

Comment: Have you tried asking them what their recipe is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic question is how to work with your dried bhut jolokia chili peppers.

First and foremost, don gloves (and, afterwards, remove them so that they're inside out).

To rehydrate the pods, put them in a bowl and pour boiling water over them, enough to cover them.  Cover the bowl with plastic wrap and let it sit until the chilies are softened, at least 10-15 minutes. As though you needed them to be more intense (really), you could toast the dry pods (both sides) in a hot, dry skillet, before rehydrating.

As for the dip, follow any recipe for queso, such as your Velveeta approach, with sauteed meat, onions, and tomatoes.